# HikariCP with grails 5 not works

Tags: spring-boot, grails, hikaricp

I'm trying to integrate HikariCP DB connection pool to new Grails 5.2.4 application (based on spring boot 2.7) without any success.

For grails 3 & 4 it works from the box: just add dependancy to build.gradle and double check dataSource.pooled property (have to be true)

```
  implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.22'
  implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.0.1'
```

But with version 5 of grails happance nothing. I don't see any log messages, debugger not stopping on HikariDataSource constructor breackpoints.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Default build.gradle contains:

```
runtimeOnly "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
```

That line have to be removed. Otherwise tomcat jdbc pool will be used instead of HikariCP